# Extract URL from SCRIPT portion of HTML Code with RegEx

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have one URL which is inside a `<script>` tag and I need to extract that URL:

Using `ReMatchNoCase()`, I can find the script and place it in an array.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" > //alert("a chance stuff"); document.location.href="https://mypage.cfm"; </SCRIPT>
```

To extract the URL, I am using the following code

```
<cfset ulink = reMatchNoCase("<SCRIPT.*?>.*?</SCRIPT>", data)>
<cfset link = Replacenocase(Replace(listLast(ulink[1],'='),'"','','ALL'),';</script>','','all')>
```

This works, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ReFind/NoCase()` is not designed to return the actual substring, this is about as simple as you're going to get.

```
<cfset data='<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" > //alert("a chance stuff"); document.location.href="https://mypage.cfm"; </SCRIPT>'>
<cfset ulink = reMatchNoCase("<SCRIPT.*?>.*?</SCRIPT>", data)>
<cfset link = Rematchnocase("http[^""']*",ulink[1])>
<cfoutput>#link[1]#</cfoutput>
```

Which is *a little* simpler than what you're doing. Alternatively you could use `Mid(ulink[1]...)` but with subexpressions from a `ReFindNoCase()`, but it is also no simpler.

The regular expression I use to match the URL is very generic, but it should easily do for the task. It simply captures everything until it finds a quote or apostrophe.

I did also think of this

```
<cfset data='<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" > //alert("a chance stuff"); document.location.href="https://mypage.cfm"; </SCRIPT>'>
<cfset ulink = rereplacenocase(data,"[\s\S]*?(<script.*?>[\s\S]*?(http[^""']*)[\s\S]*?</script>)[\s\S]*","\2","ALL")>
<cfoutput>#ulink#</cfoutput>
```

which is possibly better, but it is so much nastier to read and is less reliable for dealing with multiple `<script>` tags if that should arise.

Personally, I'd go with the first route. With RegEx, sometimes the "lazier" you try to be, the shakier the whole thing becomes. It's best to define the best pattern you can to attain your goal and in ColdFusion, I believe the first route is the best route.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<cfset data = '<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" > //alert("a chance stuff"); document.location.href="https://mypage.cfm"; </SCRIPT>' />
<cfset start = REFindNoCase("<script[^>]*>", data) />
<cfset match = REMatchNoCase("https?://[^'""]*(?=.*</script>)(?!.*<script>)", mid(data, start, len(data) - start + 1)) />
```

In the second line I am finding the position of the `<script>` open tag (even though not absolutely necessary for this particular piece of data). In the 3rd line I find any URLs within the `<script>` tag. I use positive lookahead to make sure that there is a `</script>` end tag following, and *negative* lookahead to make sure there is not another `<script>` tag.